# Partion of a vector to a list

Tags: r

Let `v` be  a  vector as follows:

```
> v <- seq_len(90) 
> v
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9,.....
```

For any number,e.g. 3, How to get a list as follows;

```
>foo(v,3)

[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 4 5 6

[[3]]
[1] 7 8 9

    ......
```

---

Comment: `split(v, rep(1:length(v), each = 3, length.out = length(v)))`

Comment: I have reopened the question as your second question was different but I think you have edited it again?

Comment: I am sorry for confusing you. Please set duplicate !! I am sorry and thank you !!